# Error while running End to End - An unhandled exception occurred: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, webdriver

When running "**ng e2e**" throws below error,

```
An unhandled exception occurred: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.exe'
See "C:\Users\Sanjai\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-RVEGxk\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Below is the **angular-errors.log**

```
[error] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver.exe' -> 'D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.exe'
    at Object.renameSync (fs.js:661:3)
    at unzip (D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:240:8)
    at D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\cmds\update.js:205:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async execute (D:\AmazeCommerce\AmazeCommerce-App\amaze-commerce\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\protractor\index.js:72:9)
```

Any one get me out of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's self explanatory. It's looking for a specific version of chromedriver and sees a generic one. You can try renaming it and hope that it's the one you need. Or download chromedriver_88.0.4324.96 and use that

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov But chromedriver_88.0.4324.96.exe already exists in the specified file?